# Implementing a remote shell server in python

Tags: python, shell, networking

I am writing a remote shell server in python.Here how it works.

1-The client connect to the server.
2-The server prompt the client to login.
2-After that the user can send a shell command to the sever. 
3-The sever execute the command.

Here is a snippet of the server code that handle the coming requests

```
cmd=sock.recv(8192)  
output = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(),stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()
sock.send(output)
```

My problem is that I want the server to handle multiple clients and I want every client to have a separate shell session.

edit:

I want the server to start a new instance of the shell whenever it receives a new connection from a client and keep that instance in memory until the connection closes.

Comment: Hey there. It doesn't seem that you've actually asked a question :(

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it that for every connected client you server starts a thread, just for that client and handles his commands. Something like:

```
def client_handler(socket, address):
    # receive client commands and do whatever is necessary

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Socket, Bind, Listen
    while True:
        # Wait for connection and accept
        thread.start_new_thread(client_handler, (socket, address))
```